# Get field from postgres record type in SQLAlchemy

Tags: postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a query that returns a record, and I need to access a field on this record.

I can use this with postgres (`items.properties` is a `jsonb` column):

```
SELECT (p).key FROM items, jsonb_each(items.properties) p;
```

How can I make this query in sqlalchemy?

I have this so far:

```
properties_data = func.jsonb_each(ItemModel.properties).alias("p")
q = db.query(properties_data).select_from(ItemModel)
```

This produces the following, but I cannot find a way to access `key` field on `p`:

```
SELECT p.jsonb_each_1 AS p_jsonb_each_1 
FROM stac.items, jsonb_each(stac.items.properties) AS p
```

I should mention I don't want to return values in python and access `key` there. I'm going to use this query as a subquery in another query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is ["table valued functions"](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/dialects/postgresql.html#table-valued-functions), it shows an example for `json_each` which can be trivially modified for `jsonb_each`.

Here is a self contained code snippet running in SQLAlchemy 2 that selects only the `key` from the result.

The lines of interest are as follows, note that you have to pass `joins_implicitly=True` to avoid a warning related to cartesian product as [suggested by docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/20/core/functions.html#sqlalchemy.sql.functions.FunctionElement.table_valued.params.joins_implicitly)

```
    properties_data = func.jsonb_each(ItemModel.properties).table_valued('key', joins_implicitly=True)
    statement = select(properties_data.c.key).select_from(ItemModel)
```

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, select, func
from sqlalchemy.orm import Mapped, DeclarativeBase, Session, mapped_column
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB


class Base(DeclarativeBase):
    pass


class ItemModel(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'items'
    id: Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True)
    properties: Mapped[dict[str, str]] = mapped_column(JSONB)

engine = create_engine('connection string')
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session(engine) as session:
    session.add(ItemModel(properties={'foo': '1', 'bar': '2'}))
    session.add(ItemModel(properties={'bax': '3', 'qux': '4'}))
    session.commit()

with Session(engine) as session:
    properties_data = func.jsonb_each(ItemModel.properties).table_valued('key', joins_implicitly=True)
    statement = select(properties_data.c.key).select_from(ItemModel)
    for i in session.scalars(statement):
        print(i)
```

Output

```
bar
foo
bax
qux
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know about `table_valued`. With some modifications for my own use case, this did the job. :)

Comment: Glad to know it helped @kaveh. Just curious, was it just modification for the older 1.x query style and making this a subquery or was it something different?

Comment: It was mostly about accessing fields on a record (in my case created by jsonb_each). I didn't know outputs of `func` objects have a column (`c`) attribute that gives you the fields on them. And then there was a part about putting it into a subquery.